# Resemplig and adding missing rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a dataframe that represent 1 Sec of data that supposed to be sample at 100 Hz.

I would like to 
1) `resample` it  which  at the rate of 10 Millisecond with "avg" approach for each column and 2) add extra rows based on interpolation approach when missing, as in the following:

DF_input:

```
ephoc_as_datatime         att1 att2
2000-01-01 11:22:37.130    0    4
2000-01-01 11:22:37.138    1    5
2000-01-01 11:22:37.149    2    6
2000-01-01 11:22:37.156    3    7
2000-01-01 11:22:37.165    4    8
2000-01-01 11:22:37.168    5    9
2000-01-01 11:22:37.169    3    7
2000-01-01 11:22:37.567    7    3
2000-01-01 11:22:38.120    8    4
```

DF_output:

```
ephoc_as_datatime         att1 att2
2000-01-01 11:22:37.130    0    4
2000-01-01 11:22:37.140    1    5
2000-01-01 11:22:37.150    2    6
2000-01-01 11:22:37.160    3    7
2000-01-01 11:22:37.170    4    8
....adding the missing one
2000-01-01 11:22:37.570    7    3
....adding the missing one
2000-01-01 11:22:38.120    8    4
```

I know that I should be using `resample` and `interpolate`. 
Please, any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Best Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `10L` for `10ms` with [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes
#df['ephoc_as_datatime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ephoc_as_datatime'])

df = df.resample('10L', on='ephoc_as_datatime').mean().interpolate()
print (df.head(20))
                          att1   att2
ephoc_as_datatime                    
2000-01-01 11:22:37.130  0.500  4.500
2000-01-01 11:22:37.140  2.000  6.000
2000-01-01 11:22:37.150  3.000  7.000
2000-01-01 11:22:37.160  4.000  8.000
2000-01-01 11:22:37.170  4.075  7.875
2000-01-01 11:22:37.180  4.150  7.750
2000-01-01 11:22:37.190  4.225  7.625
2000-01-01 11:22:37.200  4.300  7.500
2000-01-01 11:22:37.210  4.375  7.375
2000-01-01 11:22:37.220  4.450  7.250
2000-01-01 11:22:37.230  4.525  7.125
2000-01-01 11:22:37.240  4.600  7.000
2000-01-01 11:22:37.250  4.675  6.875
2000-01-01 11:22:37.260  4.750  6.750
2000-01-01 11:22:37.270  4.825  6.625
2000-01-01 11:22:37.280  4.900  6.500
2000-01-01 11:22:37.290  4.975  6.375
2000-01-01 11:22:37.300  5.050  6.250
2000-01-01 11:22:37.310  5.125  6.125
2000-01-01 11:22:37.320  5.200  6.000
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df.resample('10L', on='ephoc_as_datatime').mean().head(20))
                         att1  att2
ephoc_as_datatime                  
2000-01-01 11:22:37.130   0.5   4.5
2000-01-01 11:22:37.140   2.0   6.0
2000-01-01 11:22:37.150   3.0   7.0
2000-01-01 11:22:37.160   4.0   8.0
2000-01-01 11:22:37.170   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.180   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.190   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.200   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.210   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.220   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.230   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.240   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.250   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.260   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.270   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.280   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.290   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.300   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.310   NaN   NaN
2000-01-01 11:22:37.320   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Just curious, what is interpolate doing here ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat - default method is `linear`, check [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

Comment: @CarloAllocca - I want only show what data are `NaN`s before interpolate :)

Comment: Perfect. Problem Solved. Many Thanks Juzrael.